# Some USB devices disconnecting when moved or bumped

Tags: laptop, usb

I have a Toshiba laptop, had this laptop since 2013 I think.

I use it everyday and connect it to an LCD monitor and I plug USB mouse and keyboard to use it.

Then suddenly it’s broken like hell, when you simply bump it or move it the mouse and keyboard will disconnect for a while and then it will reconnect again.

It doesn't happen when you plug USB lights or fan and that's about it everything you plug to it will disconnect and reconnect when you move it even my audio interface.

I thought maybe it was just dirty so tried cleaning it with a Q-Tip but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is the laptop still under warranty? If yes I would contact the manufacturer and see what the guys there would say.

If no I would take it to a technician as the USB ports or something in the connection to the motherboard may be loose and any movement may be disconnecting the ports from the computer.

I would verify this by trying these devices on other computers and see if movement causes similar issues.

Comment: no, the laptop is not under warranty and i dont want to spend any money to fix it because its almost 4 years old. and yes the other devices works fine on other computers

Comment: In that case, if you feel comfortable opening the laptop and attempting things at your own risk, you may check if something is loose inside and if everything is still connected properly, especially the USB ports. 
Another option is a PSU problem as it may not be delivering adequate power to the peripherals for some reason but I don't think this is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

If your warranty is up, and you don't want to spend money on fixing it, then you might as well forget about the faulty USB ports for good.

But if you do have other USB ports in good condition (and you feel they aren't enough), you can get a USB hub and connect your non-storage USB devices into the hub, which in turn is connected to a working USB port.

USB storage devices utilize as much bandwidth as they can get - say, if you plug in 2 flash drives into the hub, both will work only half as fast, as they both use the same USB port on your laptop.

Comment: im using a usb port and its still disconnecting when you move it

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue. If a touch the USB drive, it disconnects and if I touch it again, it'll reconnect. This is not a Windows or OS issue, is a port/connector issue. I think some of the peripheral cables have a somewhat smaller or thinner enclosure that does not allow the connection to be firm.

I have tried to raise the two connector pins at the bottom of the port but that does not help because there is too much space around the male USB plug.

My solution was to use a USB hub. Apparently the male connector is wider than the others so, it stay in place unless is moved a little harder.